# SQL Server 2008 Analysis Management objects work with SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

Can SQL Server 2008 Analysis Management objects API work with SQL Server 2005 install?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it can, and the API wraps a fairly well documented web service interface called XML/A.  The SQL Server 2008/2008R2 management software will work with SSAS 2005 cubes as well.